# Execute operation in one specific dimension of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem with executing a given operation on a n-dimensional array. In the specific I have an array whose dimension is 5:

```
In [223]: data.ndim
Out[223]: 5
```

and with a shape equal to:

```
In [224]: shape(data)
Out[224]: (6, 26, 27, 6, 50)
```

What I would like to know is if it is possible to execute an operation on the last dimension for all the other dimension (for example `max(data[0,0,0,0,:])`) but without using any for loop.

I hope I was clear enough! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`out[i,j,k,l] = max(data[i,j,k,l,:])` can be spelt as one of the following

```
out = np.max(data, axis=-1)
out = np.max(data, axis=4)
```

Often it's useful to keep the dimensions though, as `out2[i,j,k,l,0] = max(data[i,j,k,l,:])`. You can do this by passing:

```
out2 = np.max(data, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
```

So `out2.shape == (6, 26, 27, 6, 1)` - this is handy because now it broadcasts correctly against the input.

For more info, take a look at the arguments for [`ufunc.reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html), which `sum` and `max` are both thin wrappers around

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of the axis function but what I do not get is how can I execute any other operation. For example now I want to normalize my data (still talking of the fifth dimension) by dividing for the maximum I just found, is it possible without any for loops?

Comment: That would be `data / np.max(data, axis=-1, keepdims=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Most functions in numpy take an `axis` keyword argument for this purpose:

```
data.max(axis=4)
```

This will find the maximum over the 5th axis (they start at 0).  The result will be of shape `(6, 26, 27, 6)`.